# JRE gives NullPointerException when it should not

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My code is

```
public class Test {
    public class Struct {
        public int id;
    }
    Struct s[] = new Struct[10];
    public Test() {
        s[0].id = 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

It gives an error in line s[0].id = 0;
However s is initialized, so I can't understand why it is giving an error.

Comment: of course it throws `NullPointException` buddy, try to init `s[0]` like this `s[0]=new Struct();s[0].id=10;` :)

Answer (score 8):

You have initialized `s`, but you also have to initialize `s[0]`.

```
    s[0] = new Struct();
    s[0].id = 0;
```

When an array is created all of its elements are set to [the default value of the element type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). For reference types (like here) the default value is `null`, so `s[0]` stays `null` until something is assigned to it.

The exception to this rule is of course when the creation of multi-dimensional arrays: when you write `new type[N][M]` the intermediate N arrays of length M are created for you, although their contents, too, will be set to the default value of the element type.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating and initializing a new array Object, but that array object has to have its own objects also initialized, as they are null by default.

```
s[0] = new Struct();
s[0].id = 0;
```

Will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the array but not references that are in the Array so you have to initialize them before using.

```
s[0] = new Struct();
```

there is nothing that is pointed by s[0] s you have to first give it a Thing(Object) that it gonna refer. so for using any reference in the array you have too initialize whole array:

```
for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
s[i] = new Struct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets see how it works,

when you are creating Test object inside main method, lets see what happens,

you're Test() constructor will be called, inside which you are doing

> "s[0].id = 0"

But Hey wait.. isnt you're Struct array s[] still having nulls?

**PS: please note when you create an object array, it is initialized with null values.
Like when you create an int array int[] all elements of the array are initialized with default value (i.e. Zero's), Similary when you create an object[], all the elements are initialized with null value by default.**

so basically you are setting id property of s[0] which is null and hence a NullPointerException is thrown by JRE